# How to draw/design a state machine with multiple threading

Tags: uml, finite-state-machine

I'm developing a module, which is very complicated. I'm trying to draw a state machine but I don't know if a state machine can present multiple threading cases.

Basically, the module processes the multi-threading inputs. For example, if input `a` and input `b` are coming together, the state would change from `stateA` to `stateB`. If input `a` is coming alone, the state would change from `stateA` to `stateC`. If input `a` has entered into the module and it is being processed by the module while input `b` is coming, the state would change from `stateA` to `stateD`.

In this case, I don't know how to present these different situations in a state machine.

Comment: This question is too vague to get useful answers. What are your inputs (in real life)? It's hard to understand what "coming together" means -- it sounds like a "third" input (c == a+b). What are "multi-threading inputs"? Are they asynchronous events arriving on different threads? If you must have different threads, they can have separate memory (and communicate via messages) or shared memory. State machines typically assume the state is global, or as @kiwiron says in his answer there's a single thread for processing events.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Well, I have got the very helpful answer. I would say you have too few experience of coding, that's why you think this question is too vague. If you have developed a game or a complex web server, you wouldn't say this is too vague. BTW, I didn't downvoted anyone.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I can't make it more clear because 1) this real case is too complicated. Many logic module mixed up together, I don't want to write a huge article here. 2) What I have post is enough, otherwise I couldn't get the other two helpful answers.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator This is a design question, not a specific technique question. You need to read this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget the notion of events coming at the same time. This doesn't happen in reality (notwithstanding contrived thought experiments involving general relativity.)

Every input event may lead to a state change and additional actions. If you want to handle events while processing of previous events is still happening, introduce an intermediate state `stateA_inProgress` in which `b` events lead to `stateD`.

If you want to handle events `a` and `b` happening closely together in time (that's the best approximation we have for "at the same time") then you need to enter a waiting state and start a timer when the first event happens, and switch to the respective target state when either the timer expires or the second input event arrives.

However, it is unlikely that you really need this. If you could edit your question to state the actual problem you're trying to solve, it might be easier to find a solution. As it stands, this looks like either an XY problem or a hypothetical question without sufficient understanding of state machines.

Answer (score 0):

The classical way to deal with this situation is to create a single-threaded management process that spawns a worker thread to handle each request. This allows the state diagrams to be independent of threading concerns. There will be a state diagram for the manager and a separate state diagram for the worker. There will of course be multiple copies of the worker running at any time but apart from some basic mutithreading issues (eg writing to a common output file) the workers will be independent processes and a state diagram is adequate to document them

Comment: My bad. In fact, my real case is a http api. So it's not a standard multi-threading pattern. But many inputs can come together. The response to client depends on the state of the api.

Comment: @Yves Sorry I don't follow your logic. Http is very much a standard multithreading pattern. Servers like Tomcat are an example. Perhaps you could expand on what you mean by "inputs can come together" and "API state" as these are not clear to me

Comment: @Dowmvoters Can you please give your reasons so I can improve or possibly delete my answer. Anonymous down voting is making this forum less than pleasant to be part of. Please stop this cowardly behavior.

Answer (score 0):

State machines themselves have no concept of multithreading. The technique for dealing with complexities in a state machine is .. more states.

> For example, if input a and input b are coming together, the state would change from stateA to stateB.

You need to be a bit more precise about "together": do you mean "in the same message being processed by the same thread", or do you mean "simultaneously in different threads"? In the latter, there is no real simultaneity if they are executing on different cores.

> If input a is coming alone, the state would change from stateA to stateC. If input a has entered into the module and it is being processed by the module while input b is coming, the state would change from stateA to stateD.

You need to introduce "being processed" states. So on the arrival of input A, transition to "stateAprocessingMessageA". If you complete processing and B has not arrived, transition to state C. If B arrives, transition to state D.

This makes your state diagram much more complicated, but it sounds like that complexity is inherent in your requirements?